# Post several parameters to WebApi controller

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

Im using angular and want to pass an id int and a string from client to web api controller. The only way i can get it to work is by having a class as parameter in the receiving method that has properties that can mapp to the data being posted. It seems crazy inefficient to create a new class to receive just two parameters to for example update an object by adding an object into a collection it owns. So im trying to send a new string the collection should ad, and an id of the object that owns the collection.

Web Api Controller

```
[Route("addEquipment")]
[HttpPost]
public void AddEquipment(AddNinjaEquipmentPost newEquipment)
{

    //This works
}

public struct AddNinjaEquipmentPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NewEquipment { get; set; }
}
```

But i would like to have something like

```
[Route("addEquipment")]
[HttpPost]
public void AddEquipment(FormDataCollection data)
{

    //id = data["id"]
    //newEquipment = data["newEquipment "]
}
```

OR something like

```
[Route("addEquipment")]
[HttpPost]
public void AddEquipment(int id, string newEquipment )
{

}
```

Comment: What about sending an `JObject` as input parameter for a `POST` method?

Comment: It should work in all scenarios. how do you post to these methods? can you update your answer with angular posting. also check developer console for errors.

Comment: If you are using `webApi2` this can help you: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API , also, look at this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: You simply need to post to the controller/action using angular. Search for `$http` and `post` in this article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Web API can't handle this request out of the box. But there exists an workaround by creating a custom parameter binding: [custom parameter binder](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API)

For my previous scenario:
I sent an `JObject` to `webApi` method instead of creating a Custom Binder.

From my example:

```
public OperationResult PerformOperation(JObject details)
{          
    dynamic d = details;

    int employeeId;
    DateTime start;
    DateTime end;
    try
    {
        employeeId = (int)d.employeeId.Value;
        start = (DateTime)d.start.Value;
        end = (DateTime)d.end.Value);
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException exception) { }
}
```

I would be also interested to improve my code if another better answer will be provided :)

Answer (score 0):

For...

```
[Route("addEquipment")]
[HttpPost]
public void AddEquipment(int id, string newEquipment )
{

}
```

You can post the value in the query string.

```
POST http://localhost:1234/api/Equipment/addEquipment?id=1&newEquipment=Weights
```

There are also a few other ways to do this if you want the values in the body of the request and not in the query string.